# How to translate this medieval sentence

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, medieval-latin

I am trying to translate the following sentence:

> Si liberalitatis nostrae munere de beneficiis a deo nobis conlatis locis ecclesiasticis quiddam conferimus, id nobis procul dubio as aeternae remuneracionis praemia capessenda profuturum liquido credimus.

I can not quite figure out the meaning of this sentence, it looks confusingly written to me. Below I wrote down what I think this tries to express

Si ... conferimus

should mean something like:

> If by our generosity we bring together all charitable services at a certain ecclesiastical place

and the part

id .... credimus.

> We believe without a doubt that we get some reward if we do that.

Additionally I can not figure out the meaning of the word "remuneracionis", this is not in my dictionary and I can not find it online either. It also confuses me that conlatis ("brought together") and conferimus("we bring together") is in the same sentence. Could you explain this sentence to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be one typo in your sentence: *as* ("copper coin") almost certainly should be *ad* ("to"). Corrected in that way, here's a piece-by-piece breakdown of your sentence:

```
Si                                          If
    liberalitatis nostrae munere                by the office of our generosity 
    de beneficiis <a deo nobis> conlatis        from the benefits conferred on us by God
    locis ecclesiasticis                        to ecclesiastical places
    quiddam                                     something
    conferimus,                                 we confer
id                                          It
    nobis                                       to us
    procul dubio                                beyond any doubt
    ad <aeternae remuneracionis>                for the obtaining of the gifts of eternal recompense
        praemia capessenda
    profuturum                                  to be beneficial 
    liquido                                     clearly
    credimus.                                   we believe.
```

A more fluent translation with English word order would be:

> If, by the office of our generosity, we confer on ecclesiastical property something of the benefits conferred on us by God, we clearly believe, without any doubt, that this will help us in obtaining the rewards of eternal recompense.

Regarding your last question, "remuneracio" is a Medieval spelling for [*remuneratio*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dremuneratio).